My background services is not working correctly for realme and vivo phone
My background location services is not working correctly for realme and vivo phone.. I am using foregroundservices which is working correclty for motorolla and samsung etc..I am not getting location when my app is in background or doesn't connect to system. I need to update the location after the time interval given
I have tried many things like extra permission and broadcast receiver when I want location I am getting notification but didn't get the location
